# Вылетает приложение при очистке словаря

Tags: android, kotlin

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. При очистке словаря "newDictionary" приложение вылетает либо сразу, либо после пару фотографий/загрузок с галереи. Если его не очищать, то всё отлично, но список ListView не чистится и он постоянно мусорится предыдущими значениями с других фото

```
    private val REQUEST_IMAGE_GALLERY = 1
    private val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAMERA = 2
    private val PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA = 3
    private lateinit var imageView: ImageView
    private lateinit var btnChoosePhoto: Button
    private lateinit var btnTakePhoto: Button
    private lateinit var btnRecognize: Button
    private lateinit var imageUri: Uri
    private lateinit var listView: ListView
    val colorsMap: Map<String, String> = mapOf(
        "E100" to "GREEN", "E100(i)" to "GREEN", "E100(ii)" to "GREEN", "E101" to "GREEN",
        "E106" to "GREEN", "E120" to "GREEN", "E140" to "GREEN" 
    )
    val valuesMap: Map<String, String> = mapOf(
        "E100" to "куркумин", "E100(i)" to "куркумин", "E100i" to "куркумин", "Е100(ii)" to "турмерик", "Е100ii" to "турмерик" 

    )
    val newDictionary: MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
    var array = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
    private var recognized = ""
    private val recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS)



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view)
        btnChoosePhoto = findViewById(R.id.btn_choose_photo)
        btnTakePhoto = findViewById(R.id.btn_take_photo)
        btnRecognize = findViewById(R.id.detect_text_image_btn)

        btnChoosePhoto.setOnClickListener {
            choosePhotoFromGallery()
        }

        btnRecognize.setOnClickListener {
         
        }
        btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener {
            takePhotoFromCamera()
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Разрешение не предоставлено, запрашиваем его
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA)
        } else {
            // Разрешение уже предоставлено, можно использовать камеру
        }

    }
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                launchCamera()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun choosePhotoFromGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_GALLERY)
    }
    private fun takePhotoFromCamera() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA)
        } else {
            launchCamera()
        }
    }

    private fun launchCamera() {
        val imageFile = createImageFile()
        imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.textrecognition.fileprovider", imageFile)

        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1) // 1 - highest quality
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT, "10485760") // Maximum file size (10MB)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) // Camera orientation

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAMERA)
    }

    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        val imageFileName = "temp_image.jpg"
        val storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(null)
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName, null, storageDir)
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            when (requestCode) {
                REQUEST_IMAGE_GALLERY -> {
                    val selectedImageUri = data?.data
                    imageView.setImageURI(selectedImageUri)

                }
                REQUEST_IMAGE_CAMERA -> {
                    imageView.setImageURI(imageUri)

                }
            }
            processImage()
         
        }
    }

    private fun myDialog(){
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle("Нет результатов")
        builder.setMessage("Возможно, сканируемый товар не содержит вредных Е-консервантов в составе. Либо " +
                "распознать корректно текст не удаётся. "
                +"\nЕсли вы уверены, что фото сделано чётко, сфокусировано и без бликов, " +
                "то товар безопасен для употребления.")
        builder.setPositiveButton("ОК"){DialogInterface, i ->

        }
        builder.show()
    }

    private fun processImage() {
        array.clear()

        val drawable = imageView.drawable
        val bitmap = (drawable as? BitmapDrawable)?.bitmap
        val textResult = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_result)
        if (bitmap != null) {

            //загрузка
            val loading = LoadingDialog(this)
            loading.startLoading()
            val handler = Handler()
            handler.postDelayed(object:Runnable{
                override fun run() {
                    loading.isDismiss()
                }
            }, 3000)

            val image = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmap, 0)
            recognizer.process(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { visionText ->
                    if (visionText.text == "") {
                        myDialog()
                    } else {
                        textResult.text = "Найденные консерванты:"


                        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView)
                        recognized = visionText.text
                        val pattern = Regex("(E)\\s*(\\d+)")

                        val matches = pattern.findAll(recognized)
                        val scannedText = matches.map { it.groupValues[1] + it.groupValues[2] }.toList()
                     
                        //Log.d("", scannedText.toString())
                        //Log.d("", recognized)

                        //заполнили словарь найденными словами
                        for (text in scannedText) {
                            newDictionary[text] = "RED"
                        }
                        //сравниваем с ешками и закидываем в новый словарь
                        for((key, value) in newDictionary){
                            if(colorsMap.containsKey(key)){
                                array[key] = colorsMap[key]!!
                            }
                        }


                        for ((index, entry) in array.entries.withIndex()) {
                            val key = entry.key
                            val value = entry.value
                            Log.d("Array", "Index: $index, Key: $key, Value: $value")
                        }
                       for ((index, entry) in newDictionary.entries.withIndex()) {
                            val key = entry.key
                            val value = entry.value
                            Log.d("Dictionary", "Index: $index, Key: $key, Value: $value")
                        }

                       var  result = array
                            .filterKeys {valuesMap.containsKey(it)}
                            .map { it.key to valuesMap.getValue(it.key) }
                            .toMap()

                        val adapter = DictionaryAdapter(result, array)

                        listView.adapter = adapter


                    }
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to process image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Сделайте фото или выберите из галереи!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    private inner class DictionaryAdapter(private val dictionary: Map<String, String>, private val array2: MutableMap<String, String>) : BaseAdapter() {

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return dictionary.size
        }

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
            return dictionary.entries.elementAt(position)

        }

        fun getItem2(position: Int): Any? {
            if (position >= 0 && position < array2.entries.size) {
                return array2.entries.elementAt(position)
            } else {
                Log.e("TAG22", "Invalid position: $position")
                return null
            }
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }

        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
            val view = convertView ?: layoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false)
            val item = getItem(position) as Map.Entry<String, String>
            val item2 = getItem2(position) as Map.Entry<String, String>

            val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.text1)



            textView.text = item.key + " - "+ item.value

            if (item2.value == "GREEN" && item.key == item2.key) {
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(56, 158, 40))
                //textView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                textView.textSize = 15f
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            } else if (item2.value == "YELLOW" && item.key == item2.key) {
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 211, 0))
                // textView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                textView.textSize = 15f
            } else if (item2.value == "RED"&& item.key == item2.key){
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(186, 47, 57))
                // textView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                textView.textSize = 15f
            }
            else if (item2.value == "ORANGE" && item.key == item2.key){
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb( 255, 165, 0))
                // textView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                textView.textSize = 15f
            }

            view.setOnClickListener {
                // Получаем выбранный элемент
                val selectedItem = dictionary.entries.elementAt(position)

                // Создаем Intent для открытия активности ItemDetailsActivity
                val intent = Intent(view.context, activity_detailed::class.java)

                // Передаем данные выбранного элемента в Intent
                intent.putExtra("key", selectedItem.key)
                intent.putExtra("value", selectedItem.value)

                // Запускаем активность ItemDetailsActivity
                view.context.startActivity(intent)
            }

            newDictionary.clear()
            return view
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Некоторые ключи и значения из словарей valuesMap и colorsMap удалила, так как там очень много значений

Comment: а с какой ошибкой вылетает? приложите код ошибки

Comment: @Victoria приложение логи и код ошибки, без этой информации - пальцем в небо.